# ERROR that looks so main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd6): undefined reference to `vtable for Counter'?

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

I have naturally trivial question as I mean: we press button --> counter increases, counter increases --> QLabel's value is renewed. I caught strange error and don't want to do. I'm not dummy in C++ but in QT I am. It's my first and most trivial application in it.

Some answers there (on Stack Overflow) advised to add virtual constructor. It has no effect.

I tried to rewrite signals and slots to new qt5 style but there were another problems, I was too lazy to fix them, was it (rewriting, not laziness :) ) a good way, maybe problem is really with versions?

I just haven't tried to reinstall QT or install Qt4, maybe problem is in it?

**about versions:**

```
$ qmake --version
```

responds:

```
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

**conn.pro:**

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += core gui

TARGET = conn
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QObject>

class Counter : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    double i_;

public:
    virtual ~Counter()
    {

    }
    Counter() : QObject(), i_(0)
    {
    }


public slots:
    void slot_incCounter();

signals:
    void goodbye(){}
    void counterChanged(double){}
};

void Counter::slot_incCounter() {
    emit counterChanged(++i_);
    if (i_ == 5) {
        emit goodbye();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication my_app(argc, argv);

    QLabel label1("label i created");
    label1.show();

    QPushButton button1("press me");
    button1.show();

    Counter counter1;

    QObject::connect(&button1, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     &counter1, SLOT(slot_incCounter()));

    QObject::connect(&counter1, SIGNAL(counterChanged(double a)),
                     &label1, SLOT(setNum(double a)));

    QObject::connect(&counter1, SIGNAL(goodbye()),
                     &my_app, SLOT(quit()));

    return my_app.exec();
}
```

Try to run it:

```
qmake && make && ./conn
```

So I see in console:

```
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o conn main.o   -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd6): undefined reference to `vtable for Counter'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:144: recipe for target 'conn' failed
make`:` *** [conn] Error 1
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much! Your answer was full, useful and making all more obvious. 
Solution was:
**1. Move class Counter to Counter.h**
Since this moment the message about vtable disappeared. Appeared messages that  goodbye() and Counter::counterChanged(double) have multiple definition. The first definition was mine in Counter.cpp (WRONG WAY). The second was in moc_Counter.cpp, generated by MOC utility. So:

**2. Remove definitions (my empty definitions) of signal functions**, because moc makes its own in file moc_Counter.cpp:

```
// SIGNAL 0
void Counter::goodbye()
{
    QMetaObject::activate(this, &staticMetaObject, 0, Q_NULLPTR);
}

// SIGNAL 1
void Counter::counterChanged(double _t1)
{
    void *_a[] = { Q_NULLPTR, const_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<const void*>(&_t1)) };
    QMetaObject::activate(this, &staticMetaObject, 1, _a);
}
```

and they cause a problem of multiple definition.

Summing it up, working code:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "Counter.h"



int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication my_app(argc, argv);

    QLabel label1("1");
    label1.show();

    QPushButton button1("press me");
    button1.show();

    Counter counter1;

    QObject::connect(&button1, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     &counter1, SLOT(slot_incCounter()));

    QObject::connect(&counter1, SIGNAL(counterChanged(double)),
                     &label1, SLOT(setNum(double)));

    QObject::connect(&counter1, SIGNAL(goodbye()),
                     &my_app, SLOT(quit()));

    return my_app.exec();
}


void Counter::slot_incCounter() {
    emit counterChanged(++i_);
    if (i_ == 5) {
        emit goodbye();
    }
}
```

**Counter.h:**

```
#ifndef COUNTER_H
#define COUNTER_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QObject>

class Counter : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    double i_;

public:
    virtual ~Counter()
    {
    }

    Counter() : QObject()
    {
    }


public slots:
    void slot_incCounter();

signals:
    void goodbye();
    void counterChanged(double);
};

#endif // COUNTER_H
```

**Counter.cpp:**

```
#include "Counter.h"
```

Thank you, you're great!

Comment: You are welcome. A further note of advice: If you are using Qt5 make a habit of using the new connect syntax since it is type safe and checked at compile time: `QObject::connect(&button1, &QPushButton::clicked, &counter1, &Counter::slot_incCounter);`.

Answer (score 1):

Qt uses the meta object compiler (moc) to enable e.g. signal and slots. By default it works perfectly if the Q_OBJECT macro is in a header file. So the easiest would be you put `Counter` into it's own header/implementation file, rerun `qmake` and `make`. (That's by the way good practice...)

If you want to stick with a single main.cpp file you need to tell the moc explicitly that this file contains macros moc needs to parse. You do this with the following line at the very end of main.cpp:

```
#include "main.moc"
```

Then also rerun `qmake` and `make`.

Please keep in mind that the manually including a moc-include directive is not the best choice. So better split your C++ classes into separate files right from the beginning...

Comment: Moving it to the .h works. Didn't try second way. Thank you for your full answer!